# MiniProfiler Reporting for Logged data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-mini-profiler

Is there any tool like MiniProfiler for ASP.net MVC3 or something similar but with little more features like aggregated results.

Currently MiniProfiler is great to understand & measure individual page requests performance. But it is not storing/logging anything for reporting. I'm looking for something that can continuously monitor & record the same and gives us an ability to filter what was the slowest queries in application during some point of time?

Comment: this is exactly what im trying to do at home and i've also emailed Sam Saffron to talk about that. I can't tell you if i can deliver something anytime soon but this is something i want to work on for sure.

Comment: Hi, it will be a great. Let's make that happen, and work together for this. If you want we can discuss about it. Let me know by commenting here.

Comment: It would be great. Let's see what we can do together! But i don't want to put my email here. How can i contact you?

Comment: I'm also concerned abt giving my email id here. Although you can contact me using form from this page, then we can initiate a chat on this: http://www.xcellence-it.com/contact/

Comment: @AlexandreJobin I'd love to collaborate on this. Lets start this together. We can devote few hours everyweek for this. What do you think?

Comment: i emailed you with the contact form on xcellence-it.com 2 days ago. Maybe they havent forwarded the email to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MiniProfiler to store results in something other than the default HttpCache. Just set `MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage` to be something other than the default (which is `HttpRuntimeCacheStorage`) during your setup in Global.asax.cs. You can use one of the providers included in [StackExchange.Profiling.Storage](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/tree/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Storage) (the most likely candidate being [SqlServerStorage](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Storage/SqlServerStorage.cs)), or come up with your own implementation of [IStorage](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Storage/IStorage.cs) to use for whatever storage medium you would like. You should then be able to report on the  profiling data as needed based on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for answering.. We did the same as you suggested.